# How do I make Multiple API Calls?

Tags: javascript, api

I am pretty new to Javascript and APIs, and I really want to learn more about them! I have been following some tutorials with some very simple APIs, but I have run into a problem when trying to make multiple API calls.

I made a function with getting the info from the API inside, but when I call it multiple times, just manually or by for loop, it only accurate integrates the last one with my `html` file.

I'm pretty new, so I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong in this case. I am using the Pokemon API found here: https://pokeapi.co/

```
const app = document.getElementById('root')

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.append(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

function getPokemon(pokeNum) {
    request.open('GET', 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokeNum + '/', true);

    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data);

        const card = document.createElement('div');
        card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.textContent = data.name;

        const frontSprite = document.createElement('img');
        frontSprite.src = data.sprites.front_default;

        container.appendChild(card);
        card.appendChild(h1);
        card.appendChild(frontSprite);
        console.log(data.name);
    }
    request.send();
} 
getPokemon(2);
getPokemon(3);
```

For example, in the `request.onload` part of the function when I try to `console.log(data.name)` only the name of the `getPokemon(3)` call is displayed in the console and not `getPokemon(2)`

Comment: try moving `var request = new XMLHttpRequest()` *inside* the `getPokemon` function

Comment: You can't use the same `XMLHttpRequest` object for multiple requests at the same time.